# Aspose.Cellsで生成するPDFにフォントを埋め込みたくない

Tags: java, pdf

Aspose.Cells for Java (ver8.5.0)を使って、ExcelのテンプレートからPDFを生成しています。
このExcelテンプレートにはMS PゴシックなどのMS系フォントを使用しています。
アプリケーションの形態はWebアプリケーションで、APサーバはWildflyです。

このアプリケーションを、WindowsServerで動かした場合は問題ありません。
しかし、CentOS上で動かすと、PDFが文字化けを起こしてしまいます。
現象から推測するに、PDF生成の際、サーバ側にインストールされているフォントに依存するような処理がされてしまっていそうです。
PDFにはフォント埋め込みの仕組みがありますから、恐らくそれが有効になっているのではないか、と。

【追記】
labunixさんの回答のリンクを参考に、実際に埋め込まれているフォントを確認しました。

**Windows Server で生成したPDF　→　文字化けする**
[image: WindowsServer]

**CentOS で生成したPDF　→　文字化けする**
[image: CentOS]

**CentOS (IPAフォントインストール済み) で生成したPDF　→　文字化けしない**
[image: CentOS(IPA)]

【追記ここまで】

CentOSにMS系フォントをインストールすることは、ライセンス上NGです。
このアプリケーションのクライアント環境はWindowsを想定していますので、「クライアントにMS系フォントがインストールされていれば閲覧できる」という状態にしたいです。
フォント埋め込みさえ無効化できれば、それが実現できるのではないかと踏んでいます。

ここまでの推測は正しいのでしょうか。
正しい場合、Aspose.Cells for Javaで、この設定を切り替えられるAPIはどれなのでしょうか？

Comment: 環境によって文字化けしたりしなかったりするということはPDFにフォントが埋め込まれて**いない**からですね。おそらく今回の意図としてはフォント情報(font information([参考](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/Fonts+embedding+while+creating+PDF)))のことを指したいのだと思いますが、これを取り違えているため回答者も混乱している気がします。

Comment: 「サーバ環境」によって文字化けしたりしなかったりしますが、「クライアント環境」はWindows固定なので、無関係です。実際に、PDFのプロパティで、KhmerOScontent, NanumGothic, UMingTWMBEというフォントが「埋め込みサブセット」となっているのを確認しました

Comment: 回答から頂いた情報をもとに追記しました

Answer (score 1):

まず、埋め込みフォントがMS系フォントなのか、Adobe系フォントなのかは、
それぞれ、作成されたPDFのプロパティから埋め込みフォントについて確認してみてください。

http://www.matsucollo.co.jp/homepage/comic/datamake/pdf_font.html

上記のMS系埋め込みフォントの問題であれば、代替フォントであるIPAフォントを
CentOSにインストールしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

http://ipafont.ipa.go.jp/old/ipafont/download.html

APIについては知識がありませんが、下記マニュアルでは不十分でしょうか。

www.aspose.com/api/java/pdf/com.aspose.pdf.text/classes/SystemFontsSubstitution

Comment: WindowsServer上で動かすと、MS Gothicが埋め込まれています。CentOS上で動かすと、KhmerOScontent, NanumGothic, UMingTWMBEというフォントが埋め込まれていますね・・・ExcelテンプレートはMS系フォントに最適化してたくさん作ってしまったので、できればフォント変更なしで対処したいです

Comment: 実際に使用するフォントには影響ないはずです。CentOSでは以下のようになっていますか？
$ fc-list | grep --color -i IPAgothic
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/ipafont-gothic/ipag.ttf: IPAゴシック,IPAGothic:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-japanese-gothic.ttf: IPAゴシック,IPAGothic:style=Regular
http://news.mynavi.jp/series/acrobat_pdf2013/059/

Comment: 実際に使用するフォントには影響ないはず、とのことですが、CentOSにIPAフォントをインストールしたところ、クライアントでPDFを開くとIPAフォントが埋め込まれて表示されています。

Comment: IPAフォントの表示で文字化けるのでしょうか。文字化けが無いなら問題ないように思えますが。。http://www.aspose.com/api/java/pdf/com.aspose.pdf.text/classes/fontsourcecollection/methods/clear()/

Comment: IPAフォントでは文字化けしません。ただ、微妙の文字の位置や大きさが異なるため、MS系フォントでぎりぎりに調整した帳票だと不都合があります